# ¿Cómo grabar un campo image en SQL Server en php?

Tags: php, sql-server, imagen

Tengo una tabla con un campo tipo `image`, mi duda es como actualizar un dato en ese campo, he tratado de actualizar ese dato pero por el formato que tiene no lo he podido, no he podido hacer la conversión para guardarlo en la base de datos.

Comment: es un campo binario, por lo general el formato es jpg aunque he visto situaciones donde reporata gif y sigue siendo jpg y en algunos casos es un bitmap ( 24 bits rle 4 u 8 bits )

Comment: lo que deseo guardar es solo jpg